# Website version control

Tags: git, version-control

I'm working on a rather large website with another web developer, and we sometimes run into the problem of overriding the other person's code by uploading an older version of the files. Is there a version control system (perhaps Git???) that we can use to prevent this from happening?

Comment: Any version control system worth it's weight should prevent this.

Comment: Git is a very good choice.

Comment: @EricTjossem Yeah I think I might try to go with Git. I've never set one up on a server though. Do you know of any good resources for beginners?

Comment: Two really good resources:

http://try.github.io/levels/1/challenges/1 and 
http://git-scm.com/

Answer (score 1):

You could try Tortoise SVN for version control or some similar service. I've heard of people using Dropbox for this.

Comment: I think I'd prefer to go with a system that's self contained rather than through a 3rd party application such as Dropbox. It's an interesting thought though.